# How to control execution order for unrelated Alteryx IO tasks?

Tags: alteryx

I have 3 completely unrelated Excel files. Each needs to be uploaded to a separate database table. Unrelated files, unrelated tables. So I have 3 completely independent `Input --> Output` structures.

Once all these `Input --> Output` routines complete, then I have other code I need to execute.

The problem is I want to guarantee my "other" code doesn't start until ALL 3 Excel files get uploaded. How can I `BlockUntilComplete` for all these 3 Excel files?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the below might work... input the file paths; use multiple block-until-done's... filter the filename to work with, dynamic input to grab it, then do your upload or whatever... then later on continue on to the rest of the wrokflow. (See picture)

[image: Multiple file outputs prior to additional processing]